# How to catch ConnectionError max retriees via try except

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a problem with `ConnectionError` max retries using `try`,`except`. I am using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests`.
If my script working for about 10 hours, the script does nothing!
I am using try except and time.sleep(1) to catch this error.

```
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    sleep(1)
    try:
        req = requests.get(link, verify=False)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        logger.debug("Connection error! " + link)
        continue
    if req.status_code != 404:
        do_something()
    else:
        logger.debug("Website not exist! " + link)
        continue
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @nandukk When I catch ConnectionError, script does nothing: does nothing happen, and it does not even end.

Comment: It is possible that they blocked your ip. Then your subsequent requests will also give ConnectionError. That might be why your script does nothing after getting a ConnectionError. You cannot hit a server continuously with fixed delay and not expect to get blocked.

Comment: @nandukk thanks, can I change my IP during run script? Best

Comment: You can use a proxy service. You have to pay for premium ones. The most cost effective method to do would be to simply add a random delay of 1 - 15 secs the next time you hit their servers. You can also do UserAgent rotation etc. You can google most of this stuff.

Comment: @nandukk thanks, I try random delay! :)